# How to show pdf data from a filestream

Tags: swift, pdf, filestream, urlsession

I am working against a `REST API` where you can make a call and then receive a image or pdf. I am using `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to make the call and when there is a image the call is a success (but it takes quite a long time, more then 5 seconds) and I can show the image in a `UIImageView`. But when there is a pdf, I don't know how to handle the result. The API returns the image / pdf as a ”filestream”.

When I print the data to the console it prints the size (bytes) and its the same size as in the server so in some way I have the correct data, I just don't know how to view the pdf.

I am using swift 3, iOS 10, xcode 8.

Comment: First of all are you able to save the filestream in pdf format?  if yes then you can use webviews to show the pdf data to your app

Comment: There are a lot of explanation in this question. You better ask separately on each topic (eg. Download the pdf and save, how to read the pdf that saved)

Comment: Later today I will test the answer below - download and save with Alamofire. But, thats was never the plan from the beginning (and not in the question). I hoped that I did not need to go throw the filesystem because I need to download several pdf files and in the end I would like to show them in a collectionview. I am also not sure if I could use the filesystem in the simulator. But the nicest solution should be like I do with the images, just let image = UIImage(data: data) and then show the image in a tableview / collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you may want to ask your question into two part. Please edit it and ask the second part again.

There are two parts in this topic

**1. Downloading the PDF and save it in File System**

**2. Get the pdf that saved in File System and read it using `UIWebView` or `UIDocumentInteractionController`**

So, I will explain for the first one.

The first one can be done if you use REST HTTP client : [Alamofire : Elegant HTTP Networking in Swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). So no need to use `URLSession` for such case and you will have to write so many lines if you do. It's simple and easy. So, I want you to try it. If you need `URLSession` instead, leave comment.

So how to download pdf using `Alamofire` :

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
//.documentDirectory means it will store in Application Document Folder
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendPathComponent("data.pdf")

      return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}

Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { response in
print(response)

     if response.error == nil, let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
           // do anything you want with filePath here.
           // Here what you have to do Step 2. (Read the file that you downloaded)
     }
}
```

This download procedure doesn't include requesting download link with encoded parameters. It was just simple way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I use let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory) and then a local load in WKWebView and it works. Now I just wondering whats happens with the local file, if its deleted when I close the app and if its overwrites the file in others downloads so I am not fill up my memory. I need to check that.